# How to make one variable out of this?

Tags: php, mysql

Best,

I'm bussy making a website, but one thing holds me up..
I have to make a real long search query, and i have made this PHP code:

```php
if($_GET['genre']) { 
echo 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `genre1` = '; 
foreach($_GET['genre'] as $genre) 
{   
$genres = array( "Actie", "Animatie", "Avontuur", "Documentaire", "Drama", "Erotiek", "Familie", "Fantasy", "Film", "Horror", "Komedie", "Misdaad", "Muziek", "Mystery", "Oorlog", "Roadmovie", "Romantiek", "Sciencefiction", "Thriller", "Western" );
if (!in_array($genre, $genres)) 
{
header('location: ?error=1'); 
} 
echo " '".$genre."' OR `genre2` = '".$genre."'"; if(end($_GET['genre']) !== $genre)
{ 
echo ' OR `genre1` = '; 
} 
} 
echo " AND `year` > '".$_GET['year1']."' AND `year` < '".$_GET['year2']."';"; 
} 
else
{ 
echo "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `year` > '".$_GET['year1']."' AND `year` < '".$_GET['year2']."';"; 
}
```

On a URL like this:

```
127.0.0.1/querygenerator.php?genre%5B3%5D=Avontuur&genre%5B4%5D=Documentaire&genre%5B6%5D=Erotiek&year1=1900&year2=2014
```

And it outputs something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `genre1` = 'Avontuur' OR `genre2` = 'Avontuur' OR `genre1` = 'Documentaire' OR `genre2` = 'Documentaire' OR `genre1` = 'Erotiek' OR `genre2` = 'Erotiek' AND `year` > '1900' AND `year` < '2014';
```

So, my question is, how can i make one PHP variable out this whole, so I can run the query?
I can do this with `file_get_contents` but that's not so safe, I guess..

Thanks! 
- Karim

Comment: You want to transfer database queries as part of the request url? Don't! And certainly not without escaping the request parameters like you do. That is a mile wide security issue you open! Read about "sql injection" and "prepared statements" or at least "escaping".

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but you can replace `echo` with  `$yourVar = ` and have it in a variable?

Comment: Wouldnt it be wiser to just do a POST, and let code run in the back to what you wanna search? Cause this way your URL bar will be cluttered and easy for injections.

Comment: I would like to mention that if you use that evil double quotes to create a string, you can put array element into them like : "Element: {$array['element']}"

Comment: I know this query is unsafe, it's just a test code, i will add the mysql_real_escape_string function soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate to a string rater than echoing:

```
if($_GET['genre']) { 
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `genre1` = '; 
  foreach($_GET['genre'] as $genre) {
    $genres = array( "Actie", "Animatie", "Avontuur", "Documentaire", "Drama", "Erotiek", "Familie", "Fantasy", "Film", "Horror", "Komedie", "Misdaad", "Muziek", "Mystery", "Oorlog", "Roadmovie", "Romantiek", "Sciencefiction", "Thriller", "Western" );
    if (!in_array($genre, $genres)) {
      header('location: ?error=1');
      die(); 
    } 
    $sql = $sql . " '".$genre."' OR `genre2` = '".$genre."'"; 
    if(end($_GET['genre']) !== $genre) { 
      $sql = $sql . ' OR `genre1` = '; 
    } 
  } 
  $sql = $sql . " AND `year` > '".$_GET['year1']."' AND `year` < '".$_GET['year2']."';"; 
} else { 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE `year` > '".$_GET['year1']."' AND `year` < '".$_GET['year2']."';"; 
}

echo $sql;
```

Comment: You are a great men :)